# When is the right time to create dynamodb connection in a server application?

Tags: amazon-dynamodb

Let's assume you are developing a server-side application with express and for incoming requests, you have to access DynamoDb and retrieve something. The question is, when is the right time to instantiate the DynamoDb connection:

```
const dynamodb = new AWS.DynamoDB({
  region: process.env.AWS_DEFAULT_REGION,
});
const docClient = new AWS.DynamoDB.DocumentClient({ service: dynamodb });
```

Should I do this once for all the API handlers or should I create a new connection for each incoming request?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As a best practice, it is recommended to declare `DocumentClient` the outside the function. However, please note that `DocumentClient` is not a database connection object. [DocumentClient](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/developer/announcing-the-amazon-dynamodb-document-client-in-the-aws-sdk-for-javascript/) is just an abstraction in the `AWS.DynamoDB` namespace. The document client abstraction makes it easier to read and write data to Amazon DynamoDB with the AWS SDK for JavaScript.

Unlike RDBMS connection, it is not required to maintain the connection or connection pool to connect to DynamoDB database.

> DynamoDB is a web service, and interactions with it are stateless.
>   Applications do not need to maintain persistent network connections.
>   Instead, interaction with DynamoDB occurs using HTTP(S) requests and
>   responses.
>
> new AWS.DynamoDB(options = {}) ⇒ Object

The service object `AWS.DynamoDB` uses asynchronous request to send data to DynamoDB. The `DocumentClient` also uses this service object internally.

By default, the SDK will send asynchronous HTTP requests to DynamoDB. However, you can change the default behavior by setting the attribute `httpOptions.xhrAsync` to false.